# How to create image[] - animated button on Mouse Hover with C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make a button with animation from images, played once to the last frame on Mouse Hover event, and it's should set the original image (first "animation frame") at the Mouse leave. All images in bmp, and separated.

I just have a pieces of code, like that:

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile("button_01.bmp");
bmp.MakeTransparent(Color.Black);
```

but generally still thinking about how to. Any examples?

Early
[image]

Middle
[image]

Final
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Define form field:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

Handle two events:

```
private async void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        button.BackgroundImage = bmp2;
        await Task.Delay(1000, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        button.BackgroundImage = bmp3;
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException) { }
}

private void Button_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
    button.BackgroundImage = bmp1;
    cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
}
```